# Split T-SQL string into columns by delimiter?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a single column using a hyphen-delimited set of eight values, some of which are blank. I am attempting to split this string into columns, with each value corresponding to the position of the delimited string:

Table1:

| Record | StringValue |
| --- | --- |
| rec1 | 422100----130-1034-10901-12000 |
| rec2 | 421100--CORP--130-1034-- |
| rec3 | 423000----130-1561-- |
| rec4 | 111500------- |
| rec5 | 661300-710-CORP--355-1106-10901-10100 |

Desired Result:

| Record | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 | col8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| rec1 | 422100 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 130 | 1034 | 10901 | 12000 |
| rec2 | 421100 | NULL | CORP | NULL | 130 | 1034 | NULL | NULL |
| rec3 | 423000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 130 | 1561 | NULL | NULL |
| rec4 | 111500 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| rec5 | 661300 | 710 | CORP | NULL | 355 | 1106 | 10901 | 10100 |

I have tried a complicated series of SUBSTRING/CHARINDEX functions which will work, but I am curious if there is a more appropriate solution? When I try the PARSENAME function it returns only NULL values because there is not a value for every position in the string.

```
SELECT 
    Record
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(StringValue, '-', '.'), 1) AS col1
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(StringValue, '-', '.'), 2) AS col2
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(StringValue, '-', '.'), 3) AS col3
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(StringValue, '-', '.'), 4) AS col4
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(StringValue, '-', '.'), 5) AS col5
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(StringValue, '-', '.'), 6) AS col6
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(StringValue, '-', '.'), 7) AS col7
    ,PARSENAME(REPLACE(StringValue, '-', '.'), 8) AS col8
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you now know, `parsename()` is limited to 4 positions.

Here is a JSON option (assuming 2016+)

```
 Select A.Record
       ,Pos1 = nullif(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]'),'') --nullif() optional otherwise empty string
       ,Pos2 = nullif(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]'),'')
       ,Pos3 = nullif(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]'),'')
       ,Pos4 = nullif(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]'),'')
       ,Pos5 = nullif(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]'),'')
       ,Pos6 = nullif(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[5]'),'')
       ,Pos7 = nullif(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[6]'),'')
       ,Pos8 = nullif(JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[7]'),'')
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([StringValue],'json'),'-','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)
```

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may help users of Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and later

STRING_SPLIT(). [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but does *MS* stand for Microsoft? And does *SS* stand for SQL Server? Also, what version are you not using?