# Break up text string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2019 (v15) and am trying to split up URLs so I have each individual part.

i.e,

| URL | Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Column 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| store.example.com | com | example | store | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| demo.m.en.store.example.com | com | example | store | en | m | demo |

I've tried a few things but always end up getting in a long `REVERSE` / `CHARINDEX` / `SUBSTRING` cycle. Tried using `STRING_SPLIT`, but couldn't work out the `PIVOT` to get it to look like the above.

I've also used `PARESENAME`, but this will not work for longer strings.

**Note**: I'm trying to do this on a large scale

Comment: take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74227722/split-t-sql-string-into-columns-by-delimiter/74227778#74227778

Comment: Thank you! This didn't come up in any of my searched. I had to chuck a couple of REVERSE() in, but this totally worked!

Comment: Ah.  On second look you are in reverse order.