# How to get the 2nd substring in between delimiters with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to query data from a column that has 3 values separated by " | " as a delimiter. I'm having trouble trying to extract the second value without creating an additional column

Example of data:

{cookie_data}

732711 | 732711@soundcorp.com | 732711 Store

I want to get the email portion only.

```
SELECT 
       SUBSTRING(cookie_data, CHARINDEX(' | ', cookie_data)  + 3, LEN(cookie_data)) AS login_data,
       SUBSTRING(login_data, 0, CHARINDEX(' | ', login_data)) AS email,
FROM TABLE
```

While this solution works, I was curious if there was an easier way of doing this without generating an extra column that isn't needed other than to create the final substring.

Comment: always a good read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74227722/split-t-sql-string-into-columns-by-delimiter/74227778#74227778

Answer (score 1):

you can use string_split instead of substring
but I wrote with two ways(substring without New Column,string_split )

```
select *
from string_split('732711 | 732711@soundcorp.com | 732711 Store','|')
```

| value |
| --- |
| 732711 |
| 732711@soundcorp.com |
| 732711 Store |

1.Get Email(with PAttern):

```
select  *
from string_split('732711 | 732711@soundcorp.com | 732711 Store','|')
WHERE value  LIKE '%_@__%.__%'
```

2.Get Email(with order):

```
select value from (
        select  *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 0)) as rw
        from string_split('732711 | 732711@soundcorp.com | 732711 Store','|')

)a
where a.rw=2
```

3.Get Email(with Substring):

```
declare @m nvarchar(100)='732711 | 732711@soundcorp.com | 732711 Store'
select   SUBSTRING(@m, charindex('|', @m)+1, len(@m) - CHARINDEX('|', reverse(@m)) - charindex('|', @m))
```

Result:

| value |
| --- |
| 732711@soundcorp.com |

Comment: Does not guarantee that the three substrings will be returned in expected order

Comment: I edited my code based on a pattern(Email)