Converting nth delimiter in CSV string into columns
I have the strings in db where the serial numbers of items are together as shown here
itemTable



A_NUMBER
items




1
i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6


2
j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,i6,i7,i8


3
k1,k2,k3



I want the resultant output of this string as shown below:



Srllno1
Srllno2
Srllno3
Srllno4
SrllRest




i1
i2
i3
i4
i5,i6


j1
j2
j3
j4
j5,i6,i7,i8


k1
k2
k3





I tried this SQL statement:
SELECT
    A_NUMBER,
    items,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(items, ',', '.'), 1) AS Srllno1,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(items, ',', '.'), 2) AS Srllno2,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(items, ',', '.'), 3) AS Srllno3,
    PARSENAME(REPLACE(items, ',', '.'), 4) AS Srllno4
FROM
    db.itemtable;

But I could not get the SrlRest unless I did it manually.
I also tried with STRING_SPLIT but I wasn't successful.
CRME: https://dbfiddle.uk/i_N273aI
How to achieve the desired result ?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Paresname will fail if more that 4 elements.   If 2016+, take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74227722/split-t-sql-string-into-columns-by-delimiter/74227778#74227778

I wasn't successful what does that mean? STRING_SPLIT works just fine. It won't fix the problems introduced by this really bad design which violates the most basic design rules. If you want to query stuff, put it in proper tables. There's no order in a result set so if you want some kind of identifier it should be part of the data

You can try converting this string into JSON by surrounding it in [" and "] and replace , with "," You'll be able to use functions like JSON_VALUE or OPENJSON to query that data. In select * from openjson('["i1","i2","i3","i4","i5","i6"]') the result will have the index in the key column.

After that you can split the results based on the Key into 0,1,2,3 and >3. You can use MIN as an aggregation function for the first 4 columns and STRING_AGG for the last

@SalmanA sql server 13.0

Then JSON functions it is. Your data cannot contain special JSON characters.

I'm sure @SalmanA simply neglected to mention string_escape(...,'json')

See example with STRING_SPLIT
select A_NUMBER,min(items) items
  ,max(case when ordinal=1 then value end)Srllno1
  ,max(case when ordinal=2 then value end)Srllno2
  ,max(case when ordinal=3 then value end)Srllno3
  ,max(case when ordinal=4 then value end)Srllno4
  ,string_agg(case when ordinal>4 then value end,',') within group (order by ordinal)SrllRest
from itemTable
cross apply(select value,ordinal from string_split(items,',',1))i
group by A_NUMBER

output is



A_NUMBER
items
Srllno1
Srllno2
Srllno3
Srllno4
SrllRest




1
i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6
i1
i2
i3
i4
i5,i6


2
j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,i6,i7,i8
j1
j2
j3
j4
j5,i6,i7,i8


3
k1,k2,k3
k1
k2
k3
null
null



Demo
Thats suprise:)  For SQL Server 2017 and later
select A_NUMBER,min(items) items
  ,max(case when ordinal=1 then value end)Srllno1
  ,max(case when ordinal=2 then value end)Srllno2
  ,max(case when ordinal=3 then value end)Srllno3
  ,max(case when ordinal=4 then value end)Srllno4
  ,string_agg(case when ordinal>4 then value end,',') within group (order by ordinal)SrllRest
from itemTable
cross apply(select value,row_number()over(order by (select null))ordinal from string_split(items,','))i
group by A_NUMBER

ordinal replaced by row_number()over(order by (select null)
And for SQL Server 2016
select A_NUMBER,items
  ,max(case when ordinal=1 then value end)Srllno1
  ,max(case when ordinal=2 then value end)Srllno2
  ,max(case when ordinal=3 then value end)Srllno3
  ,max(case when ordinal=4 then value end)Srllno4
  ,COALESCE(STUFF(
   (select ','+value from(select value,row_number()over(order by (select null))ordinal 
                            from string_split(items,','))i
    where ordinal>4
     for XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, N''
  ), N'')SrllRest
from itemTable
cross apply(select value,row_number()over(order by (select null))ordinal from string_split(items,','))i
group by A_NUMBER,items

string_agg replaced by select ... XML Path
demo
Version for SQL Server 2008
with r as(
  select 1 lvl, A_NUMBER,items
    ,case when charindex(',',items)>0 then
        substring(items,1,charindex(',',items)-1)
        when len(items)>0 then items
     else null
     end SrllNo1
    ,cast(null as varchar) SrllNo2,cast(null as varchar) SrllNo3,cast(null as varchar) SrllNo4
    ,case when charindex(',',items)>0 then
        substring(items,charindex(',',items)+1,1000)
     else ''
     end SrllRest
  from itemTable
  union all
  select lvl+1 lvl, A_NUMBER,items
    ,SrllNo1
    ,cast(case when lvl=1 and  charindex(',',SrllRest)>0 then
             substring(SrllRest,1,charindex(',',SrllRest)-1)
           when lvl=1 and  len(SrllRest)>0 then SrllRest
     else SrllNo2
     end as varchar) SrllNo2
    ,cast(case when lvl=2 and  charindex(',',SrllRest)>0 then
             substring(SrllRest,1,charindex(',',SrllRest)-1)
           when lvl=2 and  len(SrllRest)>0 then SrllRest
     else SrllNo3
     end as varchar) SrllNo3
    ,cast(case when lvl=3 and  charindex(',',SrllRest)>0 then
             substring(SrllRest,1,charindex(',',SrllRest)-1)
           when lvl=3 and  len(SrllRest)>0 then SrllRest
     else SrllNo4
     end as varchar) SrllNo4
    ,case when charindex(',',SrllRest)>0 then
        substring(SrllRest,charindex(',',SrllRest)+1,1000)
     else ''
     end SrllRest
  from r where len(SrllRest)>0 and lvl<4
)
select * from r
where lvl=4 or len(SrllRest)=0
order by a_number

demo



lvl
A_NUMBER
items
SrllNo1
SrllNo2
SrllNo3
SrllNo4
SrllRest




4
1
i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6
i1
i2
i3
i4
i5,i6


4
2
j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,i6,i7,i8
j1
j2
j3
j4
j5,i6,i7,i8


3
3
k1,k2,k3
k1
k2
k3
null



2
4
k1,k2
k1
k2
null
null



1
5
k1
k1
null
null
null



4
6
k1,k2,k3,k4
k1
k2
k3
k4



1
7

null
null
null
null





OP threw a curve ball by not initially disclosing the version of SQL Server being used.  13.0 = SQL Server 2016.  STRING_SPLIT did not not include an ordinal until SQL Server 2022.  Oddly, using SQL 2016 on dbfiddle.uk says 'string_agg' is not a recognized built-in function name.  Odd since it's not running a lower compatibility level.

Surprise. The OP stated SQL Server 13 compatibility, not SQL Server 2022 (16).

The ordinals for sql 2016/2017 version is not guaranteed to be correct, so i'd probably be somewhat wary of that solution

One more for sql server 2000 xD

BTW, using order by (select null) does not guarantee anything about the order so that example should be removed.

Yes, order by (select null) does not guarantee order , by in fact  I have not seen a case where the order of the elements was not respected - rows not sorted. I think, the implementation of the STRING_SPLIT function assumes that the order is respected. It is based on sequential string parsing.

Thank you all for the interesting and helpful comments. A lot of new things for me.

Just to expand on my comment.   The concat(), converting nulls to empty strings is optional
Example
Declare @YourTable Table ([Item] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6')
,('j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,i6,i7,i8')
,('k1,k2,k3')
 
 Select Item
       ,Pos1 = concat('',JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[0]'))
       ,Pos2 = concat('',JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[1]'))
       ,Pos3 = concat('',JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[2]'))
       ,Pos4 = concat('',JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[3]'))
       ,Rest = concat(    JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[4]')
                     ,','+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[5]')
                     ,','+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[6]')
                     ,','+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[7]')
                     ,','+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[8]')
                     ,','+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[9]')
                     ,','+JSON_VALUE(JS,'$[10]')
                     )
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ('["'+replace(string_escape([Item],'json'),',','","')+'"]') ) B(JS)

Results


Please try the following solution based on SQL Server's XML and XQuery functionality.
XPath predicates /root/r[1]..., etc. do all magic.
The trailing tokens are retrieved via /root/r[position() ge 5] predicate. It is dynamic, so, no need to hardcode that part.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, items VARCHAR(200));
INSERT @tbl VALUES
('i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6')
,('j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,i6,i7,i8')
,('k1,k2,k3');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT t.*
    -- , c
    , c.value('(/root/r[1]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Srllno1
    , c.value('(/root/r[2]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Srllno2 
    , c.value('(/root/r[3]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)') AS Srllno3 
    , COALESCE(c.value('(/root/r[4]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(20)'), '') AS Srllno4  
    , REPLACE(c.query('data(/root/r[position() ge 5]/text())').value('.', 'VARCHAR(50)')
        ,SPACE(1),',') AS SrllRest        
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(items, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);

Output



ID
items
Srllno1
Srllno2
Srllno3
Srllno4
SrllRest




1
i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6
i1
i2
i3
i4
i5,i6


2
j1,j2,j3,j4,j5,i6,i7,i8
j1
j2
j3
j4
j5,i6,i7,i8


3
k1,k2,k3
k1
k2
k3





